# Should I synthesize idea one "with" or "and" idea two to arrive at idea three?

Tags: word-choice

Should I write:

> Synthesize thing one **with** thing two.

Or

> "Synthesize thing one **and** thing two"?

**Edit:**

**With** or **and**?

This is "idea x". I synthesized "idea y" **with** "idea z".

Or

This is "idea x". I synthesized "idea y" **and** "idea z".

Comment: Did you find any relevant examples from dictionary entries for "synthesize"?

Comment: What kinds of "things" are you talking about? The philosophical synthesis of ideas? Chemical synthesis? Something else? Chemists usually talk about synthesizing *from*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some examples. It is unclear what your context is. Stack Exchange expects answers to be authoritative, which in turn requires questions to be clear.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you do not understand the meaning of "synthesize".

Comment: @Hot Licks Please synthesize your suspicion with (or and?) data. That would be helpful.

Comment: The synthesis occurred about 15 seconds after I first read your question.  Did you look up "synthesis" in a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for adding some examples. Unfortunately, those examples don't clarify your intent. Try using some real examples instead of labels. The goal is to explain what *you* are trying to say. For example, if I asked whether we should say "I am" or "I is", you'd probably say "I am". But if I told you I was referring to the letter between "H" and "J", not the first-person pronoun, i.e. "I am/is the letter between H and J", you'd change your answer. We're asking for that kind of extra information to make sense of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to ideas, I found that sometimes either version was used. However, *synthesize X and Y* was slightly more popular across the board, and even had hits when *synthesize X with Y* had nothing.

To avoid false positives, I tested ideologies specifically with Google Ngram: `synthesize ______ with` vs `synthesize ______ and`. You can check these links to see the graphs:

Both *and* & *or*:

- [Christianity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+christianity+with%2Csynthesize+christianity+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=3000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Christianity%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Christianity%20and%3B%2Cc0)
- [Marxism](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+marxism+with%2Csynthesize+marxism+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Marxism%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Marxism%20and%3B%2Cc0)

*And* (but not *or*):

- [philosophy](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+philosophy+with%2Csynthesize+philosophy+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20philosophy%20and%3B%2Cc0)
- [religion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+religion+with%2Csynthesize+religion+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=3000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20religion%20and%3B%2Cc0)
- [Judaism](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+judaism+with%2Csynthesize+judaism+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Judaism%20and%3B%2Cc0)
- [Islam](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synthesize+Islam+with%2Csynthesize+Islam+and&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csynthesize%20Islam%20and%3B%2Cc0)

---

I'm not entirely sure why Christianity and Marxism are different than the others.

Comment: It's a  remarkably good choice, using  religions to explore this topic. Such a query has mostly kept out things that are results of synthesis (as you don't usually see  something like  "Christianity is synthesis of Jesus' thought" ) and the only results  that it returns talk of   combining one religion with other.

Answer (score 2):

Your intention is somewhat unclear. Synthesize means to make something by combining or creating. The first sentence creates a new thing by mixing one with two. The second means you create two different things. (Unless you were trying to say "synthesize thing three by synthesizing one, then two, then mix them together." In which case, you should say so.)  You can also synthesize (produce / create) one thing chemically, for instance, which would also imply you're using other chemicals.

Answer (score 2):

I read the question as "what preposition or conjunction goes with synthesize?"

As far as  I know, synthesize is more common with single items, weather end products or ingredients. For instance  *He succeeded in synthesizing glucose*, or *"Synthesize Knowledge into Understanding.* [1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=d8IPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1069&lpg=PA1069&dq=He%20succeeded%20in%20synthesizing%20glucose&source=bl&ots=txpv7_7JrD&sig=Q4PbBdSXuzQqmPXn6WPfErc5Hwo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi67YDD_-fOAhUDNI8KHZ3VDp4Q6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=He%20succeeded%20in%20synthesizing%20glucose&f=false)

The use of synthesize involving individual ingredients is  less common. However, it's not entirely absent. Here's an example from Wordnet :  *his operas synthesize music **and** drama in perfect harmony* [2](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SYNTHESIZE)

Comment: This is an interesting take on the question. Can you please also link to your quotes?

Comment: Added links to sources of these sentences. First one is to a book on google books, so might load slow for some people. I'd actually have liked to link google results for a query like `"synthesize * with * and *"` but in this case it does not help much.

Comment: @R.S. Isn't the `"music and drama"` the product of synthesis -as opposed to "ingredients"?

Comment: @sunra - "ingredients" is more for physical stuff like chemicals, food ... It would be a bit weird and affected usage to apply 'ingredients' to describe music.  You can, as R.S. points out, "synthesize an idea" but it would also be a bit odd to say synthesize a musical or drama --- unless it was computer generated or you used the musical instruments called "synthesizers" to produce the sound.  Where RS gives the example of "... synthesize music **and** drama ..." it's more in the sense of putting the two ideas together - not the physical act of production.

Comment: yeah.. i intended to put ingredients in quotes but forgot for some reason

Comment: I think it would be odd to "synthesize" a show even if it involved synthesizers. It is clear `music and drama` are things this fellow's operas combines -not things it has created, as I suspected for a moment.